# Using Ci/CD to publish php composer packages

Tags: php, continuous-integration, composer-php, package, drone.io

I use a CI pipline runner called Drone.

We push to drone and it runs our tests then publishes an artifact.

That could be an NPM package, a new version of an app, or a Docker image.

How can I do this with a PHP Composer package. It seems composer publishes pacakges of git tags. Usually a normal workflow is to tag a version and CI picks up that tag and attempts to publish it on the package registry .... with composer it just runs off git tags so I could have a git tag that fails CI but is published on composer... thats CRAZY!

Comment: Do you have any clear question to answer? Usually, you don't publish a tag in PHP that was not tested yet

Comment: I found the answer, using HTTP hooks to publish.